# Set a custom maps rotations for specific pages in the print composer in QGIS2.14.3

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have prepared an atlas in the print composer and want to set a different rotation on some maps.

How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under "Item Properties" of your map item, you can set the rotation (within "Main Properties"). As long as the covering layer you are using to create the atlas has a 'Rotation' field, you can use it in the "Data Defined Override".

Answer (score 1):

For general knowledge.

1. I define a polygon layer as a cover layer in the Atlas (composer). When activating Atlas> Preview Atlas can see each area as'll browsing the pages of the Atlas. Each polygon (area of interest drawn on the map) is presented to the center of each page as if a slide show.

Following the guidance of @Knightshound:

2. Back to attribute table, I created a field to store the value for the rotation with the Decimal number format; Length 12; Precision 3. With the field calculator put a zero value (0.00) in all rows and in the polygon of my interest I put a specific value - in this case 37.000 (37 degrees). In the Print Composer, Atlas,  again on that page see the map is rotated to the position that interests me.